# NSPredicate too complicated for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is my predicate:

```
fetchReguest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY users.identifier = %@", String(WLAppSettings.currentUser!.identifier))
```

Output on console for `print(fetchReguest.predicate)`

> `Optional(ANY users.identifier == "31")`

When I add a new record, it does not appear in my `UITableView`.

But when I simplify predicate to:

```
fetchReguest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH[c] 'a'")
```

Output on console for `print(fetchReguest.predicate)`

> `Optional(name BEGINSWITH[c] "a")`

It appears in my `UITableView` with nice animation. Everything is fine.

Why complexity of my `NSPredicate` have influence on work of my `NSFetchedResultsController`? Is there a way to fix this?

There is a lot of problems with `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. I am pretty sure that is because of complexity of `NSPredicate`. Any ideas?

Below is my `NSManagedObject` I created `NSPredicate` for:

```
@objc(WLWishlist)
class WLWishlist: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var identifier: Int16
    @NSManaged var name: String

    @NSManaged var users: Set<WLUser>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with:

```
fetchReguest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY users.identifier = %d", WLAppSettings.currentUser!.identifier)
```

Since the identifier is `Int16` it cannot be used with `%@`, instead `%d`.